# HTML5 : How to load element from left side menu into the right side

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hy all,
i have a very basic question, i have created a left side menu with javascript and CSS, and i simply want when i click on a menu on the left, content will be load on the right. So my html structure should be organized into two parts : Left part and right part.
So basically i want to know the best way in HTML5 to do this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use divs to divide your page in two; something like:

```
#container {
    width: 1000px;
}
#left {
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    right: 700px;
    float: right;
}

<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

you have a few options how to load the content on the right side. You could load the right content by using Ajax, but depending on how big and or complicated your site is that can be much trouble. You could simply refresh the whole page, but than you'll have to make sure your menu stays in sync. You can also put many divs on the right and just display the correct one when they click on the menu.

Comment: I thank you for your reply,
but can you give a relative solution? i don't want to fix any numbers, i want relative numbers like the left takes 30% of the screen size and right takes the 70% ... how to do it/

Comment: that's not that easy; your menu will allways have a certain width. If you give left 30% and right 70%, if your page gets wider, there'll be a lot of space between your menu and the right content. You could make your menu float right inside the left part, then you'll have white space on the left if your page is wide. It's up to you to fiddle with it and try it with different resolutions. I usually give containers like left, right and container an absolute width, so I know what I'll end up with; it makes things easier.